# Best way to get thumbnail image name from full sized image with PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking for a proper way to get the thumbnail image name from the full sized image name for a gallery page.

Currently, whenever an image is uploaded, two images are stored in the server with the following format:

`https://example.com/d9c17708d5e3cc.jpg`

`https://example.com/d9c17708d5e3cc_thumbnail.jpg`

However, only the full sized URL is stored in the database (`https://example.com/d9c17708d5e3cc.jpg`).

So far i can succesfully get the thumbnail name with this code:

```php
<?php echo substr('https://example.com/d9c17708d5e3cc.jpg', 0, -4).'_thumbnail.jpg'; ?>
```

But i'm concerned about the performance hit of this approach since potentially this gallery will load hundreds or images. What would be the proper way to get the thumbnail names?

Clarification: My performance concerns are related to server CPU resources needed to process all the URLS and serve the page. My server is low in CPU resources, once served, the page loads quickly enough because it already has lazy loading client side.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What performance are you specifically concerned with? Parsing the strings or loading images in front end or ..???

Comment: I'm concerned about the processor time needed to process all the urls (lets say when a page with hundreds of images is requested). I am not concerned with image loading performance (the webpage already has lazy loading implemented)

Comment: Well any caching you can do will definitely help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you don't need to worry about performance. But if you want to optimise performance, I can think of two things.

1. Serverside. You can store the name images separately from their extension. One column for image_name and one for image_extension. This way you can build the individual links in the view generation without much effort. `( $name . _thumbnail . $extension )`.
2. Client side: You do not load all the images at once, but only as soon as they are needed. Keyword lazy loading.

Comment: thanks, your first approach is a great idea.  My webpage already has lazy loading for images, what i'm mostly concerned about is the server side time needed to produce the gallery page. My server is lacking in processor and memory resources, and want to optimize my server side code as much as possible.

Comment: I forgot to say, i would prefer to store the images with their extension because i'd like to allow direct image viewing.

Comment: @Esquirish maybe would good idea to take a look on the entire application. you use a framwork or cms?  Or whatever goes to improve hardware.

Comment: Yeah, i will. Cheers!

Comment: you could add how to get Extension, `$ext = explode(".", $url); $ext=end($ext);`

Comment: @Barkermn01 You are right. I will update my answear soon. merci!